# Dragging the fill handle in Microsoft Excel—white-gloved hand shows up instead of black crosshair (Mac, Mojave, Excel 16.28)

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I want to "drag the fill handle" like so: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-excel-for-mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218

But for some reason, when I put my cursor in the bottom right corner, I very often [get a gloved hand cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BfPP.png) instead of the black crosshair that you would use to "drag the fill handle". This hand doesn't allow me to drag the fill handle. How can I avoid this hand showing up when I'm trying to do this?

I am using Excel 16.28 on a Mac running Mojave.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this ridiculous problem by simply zooming out and zooming back in. Apparently this is a bug in Excel, where sometimes when working at over 100% zoom, the option to drag the fill handle stops working, until you adjust the zoom to 100%.

Comment: Thank you for this! In my case, I had the exact same problem, but was already zoomed at 100%. I zoomed up to 150, back to 100, and it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for this important addition!